Show that $S_1 \times S_1$ is not a cover of $S_2$
I am trying to show that the pair $(S_1 \times S_1, F)$ where
\begin{align}
F(\theta,\phi) = 
\{ \cos(\theta)\sin(\phi), \\
 \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi), \\ 
 \cos(\phi) \}
\end{align}
is not a cover of $S_2$ in the most visual way possible. For this, I created a geodesic from $P = \{1,0,0\}$ to $Q=\{0,0,1\}$ on $S^{2}$ along with some geodesic circles $C_i$. Then, I applied $F^{-1}$ on these circles and noticed that when the circles started to getting close the north pole, the sets $F^{-1}(C_i)$ changed its topology. See the following image.

What is the correct topological description of the sets $F^{-1}(C_i)$? They were open and became closed? How does this show that the above pair is not a covering space of $S_2$?

This might be early, as you will reach it eventually, but since $S^2$ is simply connected, all of its coverings are homeomorphic to $S^2$.

Hi, thanks for your reply. Can you explain in more detail how this relates to the image above?

Topologically, $S^1\times S^1$ is a torus, which is not homeomorphic to a sphere - there are many proofs of varying flavour and levels of depth of this statement. Also note that $S^1$ is homeomorphic to an interval with both end points identified. Therefore, the topology of your circles does not change as you approach the north pole: the end points of what now looks like lines due to the specific projection you chose are indeed the same point, and they are still closed circles. You are merely seeing an artifact which is due to your visualization similar to how maps of the earth appear distorted near certain points. A final nitpick: geodesics on $S^2$ are great circles which have the same radius as the sphere itself, unlike the circles in your picture.
EDIT: Let me explain a bit more in detail what you are seeing in the picture. Essentially, you are mapping the entire surface of a sphere to a rectangle. Now you obviously know that this is not possible without cutting the sphere (Just take a look at a map of the world, and observe that some part of it will be cut in half), and therefore, any closed curve on the sphere which happens to go across the cut will also be cut and therefore appear as no longer closed.
In proper mathematical terms, what you are showing is basically a map $\varphi$ from a simply connected open subset of the sphere (which contains your circles) to a simply connected open subset of $\Bbb R^2$. As you know, a sphere is a smooth manifold, so such a map exists for every open subset of the sphere, and is in fact a bijection. Now you are claiming this rectangle to be the torus $S^1 \times S^1$, which it can easily become if you identify the opposite sides with each other. In fact, this is a standard construction of the torus in elementary topology. Here's an animation of the process:
It should not be hard for you to visualize this process done with your image, and see how what appears as lines closes back up into circles. Now, a torus is also a smooth manifold, and there also exist bijective maps $\psi$ between open subsets of the torus and $\Bbb R^2$. Now what you call $F^{-1}$ is the map $\psi^{-1}\circ\varphi$ which is, crucially, only a map between open subsets of the sphere and the torus. Locally they are the same, but the global structure is different. Your circles only occupy an open subset or the sphere and the torus,so your method is insufficient to show the global inequivalence of the sphere and the torus.

Hi, thanks for answering. By geodesic circle I mean a circle formed by geodesics centred on a point $p$. To create it, I sample a circle in the tangent space of $p$ and project them into the manifold with the exponential map. Now it is still not clear to me why the intermediate projections in $S_1 \times S_1$ (between the closed circles and the full horizontal line) are closed. Their endpoints are not on the boundary $[-\pi,\pi] \times [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Moreover, the above image gives no hint that $(S_1 \times S_1, F)$ is not a covering space of $S_2$?

imagine "unwrapping" the sphere. to this end, you make a cut going from the north pole to the south pole on what is the "back" of the sphere if we look at it like in the picture. immediately we see that this cut intersects two circles: those which contain the north pole. I strongly suspect that the third disconnected projection (which comes close to the cut) is an artifact of the computer visualization software.

You are right, I have corrected the picture. At least this, this sudden change in the circle, is not an evidence of a failed covering space? What is the correct mathematical description of this sudden behavior?

Thinking in more detail about the space $S_1 \times S_1$, it seems that the circle began as a simply connected curve and ended as a non-simply connected curve, right?

I expanded on my answer, hopefully it is clearer now.

Thank you! Can you give me a reference for this content? As visual as possible.

any introductory textbook on smooth manifolds would do. don't know which are particularly visual, but as you have seen, visualizations can make things even more complicated sometimes.
